# How to store value of highest auto_incrementing id from a mysql returned data set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get the highest value of an auto_incrementing id from a returned MYSQL query.

Essentially I have returned the last 10 records from a table called chat. these are user-submitted chat messages each assigned an auto_incremented id.

So if I return the last 10 messages to be displayed in a chat window I then intend to use AJAX to load a php script (possibly every second) that queries the database again. This time to display all chat messages which have an id greater than than the highest previous id so the chat auto-refreshes.

I intend to store the highest 'id' from the first chat block in a   $_SESSION["latest_chat_id"]. I will then query mysql ... select * from chat where  id > '{$_SESSION["latest_chat_id"]}'.

Return the MYSQL result and update the $_SESSION["latest_chat_id"] from the new returned data.

Thereafter recalling this script every second to keep updating the chat window with new chat messages.

My question is how do I get the value of the highest id form the first result set. My code is below...

```
<?php include("../database/connect.php");

      $query1 = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 10";

      $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1); ?>

         <div class="chatbox">
    <ul>    
    <?php

     while($chat_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>

    <li><?php echo $chat_row["message_id"] . "  " . $chat_row["message"] . " " .        $chat_row["message_test"] ; ?></li>
    <?php   
        }
    ?>
```

Should I do another query such as...

$query = "SELECT message_id FROM chat ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1";

Or can I access this value from the first returned data set?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: SELECT MAX(message_id)

Comment: Just select the previous highest ID from your AJAX call and send it again as a paramet for the next execution.

Comment: Thanks but I dont know how to use AJAX yet, I need to read about that first. If I select MAX(message_id) can I do this as part of the original databse query or do I do it as  a separate query? If so there is a potential discrepancy between the highest id of the first result set and the max id when querying the database again?